# How to disable or customize the default message in alert showing to stop exist page without being saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am working on react JS. I need either disable or customize the default message "Changes you made may not saved". I have used the code shown below, but there is no change in default message. Can Someone help to solve the issue.

*Code used to customize the pop up message*

```
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {

       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
       let confirmationMessage = "'It looks like you have been editing something. ";
       (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
     formRegistered &&   handleSubmit(e)
     console.log(" confirmationMessage", confirmationMessage)
      return confirmationMessage; //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    
    });
   }
   
  });
```

*code used to disable the pop up*

```
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {

       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
       let confirmationMessage = "/o ";
       (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
     formRegistered &&   handleSubmit(e)
     console.log(" confirmationMessage", confirmationMessage)
      return null; //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    
    });
   }
   
  });

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWyjJ.png
```